# Downloading Json file failed angular 2

Tags: json, angular, download

I want to Export data table to JSON file i tried these code lines

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
// tslint:disable-next-line:import-blacklist
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
handleError: any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getOrderSummary(): Observable<any> {
// get users from api
return this.http.get('assets/ordersummary.json')// , options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('mock data' + response.json());
        return response.json();
    }
)
.catch(this.handleError);
}
}
```

I put these in appcomponent.ts

```
exportToJSON() {
this.carService.getOrderSummary();
}
```

and this line in appcomponent.html

```
<button (click)="exportToJSON()" class="btn btn-primary">Export to 
JSON</button>
```

but it says that failed- no file after downloading the file , what is the reason?

THANKS :))

Comment: Wen you mean 'download', you mean retrieve, right It won't be downloaded on the user's computer. Can you show us what the full url of the json file looks like? And what's the exact error message ?

Comment: I edited the code sir

Answer (score 0):

When using the new `HttpClient` class, you don't need to call `map`

```
getOrderSummary(): Observable<any> {
// get users from api
return this.http.get('/assets/ordersummary.json')// , options)
.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

You should also add a slash at the beginning of the url so that you can call it from any deep url in your site

`/assets/ordersummary.json`

Finally, you should define `handleError`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

service:

```
getOrderSummary(): Observable<any> {
// get users from api
return this.http.get('assets/ordersummary.json')// , options);
}
```

component:

```
exportToJSON() {
this.carService.getOrderSummary()
.subscribe((a) => {console.log('result', a);}, (error) => {/*handle error*/});
}
```

and make sure, that your url is valid.